# Is there an efficient way to pass a large array of floats to GPU with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, shader, cpu

Working on a fluid simulation project. I want to perform a neighbour search and sorting on CPU as those operations involve a lot of memory writing and then pass the information to GPU to perform the rest of calculations. Is there an efficient way to do it with OpenGL? All my information is in an array of floats (or could be in an array of structures), with each value corresponding to something like position, velocity etc. I want to sort this array in some way and pass it to the shader in some form. How do I do that and will that be efficient?

Comment: Use buffer objects, for starters. If you're doing this once per frame, check out the [Buffer Object Streaming](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) page on the wiki.

Comment: Why OpenGL ? Why not CUDA or OpenCL - as the application seems to require computation based on all available pixels and not a per-pixel computation ?

Comment: Well, I don't think CUDA will work with my GPU, I am using a MacBook air with a built in Intel HD Graphics 5000. I haven't considered OpenCL though. I will read about it.

Answer (score 0):

The authoritative reference on [high-performance OpenGL buffer streaming techniques is on the OpenGL Wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming). However, your particular needs make it somewhat difficult to generate data directly into a mapped buffer.

For example, a quick-sort or merge-sort does a lot of in-buffer processes. And while insertion sorts can work directly into the destination memory, their O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance leaves a lot to be desired. So your ultimate process will be to sort your data, then copy it to the buffer.

Techniques like persistent mapping can help, but really they're not that critical for this use case. You could probably do fine just double-buffering (so that one buffer is in use by the GPU, while you're copying to the other) and using glBufferSubData with an invalidation call before doing the copy.